# How do I specify columns to include in a matrix

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008

I have a matrix that has a group filtered at the matrix level. I can't filter the SQL because it is very large and is used all over my report.

I need to be able to specify the columns to display after the filter is applied.

The end filter would look something like this
if ColumnA[value] IN Test1,Test2,Test3 OR ColumnB[name]

As you can see I want a value string filter and make sure ColumnB get displayed at all times.

Or being able to specify the columns to show in the matrix would work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a tablix and creating columns for each column I wanted to display and rows for each row item. I then used a Count(IIF()) statement to match the specific item I needed to calculate for that cell. I wanted to use the matrix so it would not be so long winded but in the end I got the job done. I have since used this method on many occasions.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter at the dataset level:  see [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2597/dataset-and-tablix-filtering-in-sql-server-reporting-services/) for more detail.

To filter a tablix, go into Tablix Properties and open up the Filters tab. You can write a Boolean expression (must evaluate to TRUE for the record to come into the Tablix) to do the filtering there.

Comment: I did not see where I could define table columns or create something that says "this field, no matter what the value" needs to be displayed.

Comment: If it's a matrix, then your group, whatever it is, is dictating the columns; e.g., if a column called Year is on the column grouping, you can control which columns are being shown by filtering which years are allowed into the matrix.

Comment: True .. but I need not just the value but I need to force a column or columns to show up also. So if my filter says only values of 1. I also need a specific column(s) even if it is 0. But only that one column. Or a specified list of columns.